# Need help in FORMAT function

Tags: vb.net

I wrote a code and want to convert the value like if user write 12, it should be converted into "12.00"
[Reffered link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16581901/how-to-convert-answer-into-two-decimal-point-in-vb-net)

I referred the link above and got a "Format" function but when I tried it in my project, it converts the value into "0.00"

My code I written below...

```
    Private Sub txtDisc_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles txtDisc.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Return Then
        txtDisc.Text = Format(txtDisc.Text, "0.00")
        txtOpeningBal.Focus()
    End If
End Sub
```

Please help me if I made any mistake in writing the code..

I am totally new with this function and also seen msdn helps but cannot understand it properly...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to convert the string `txtDisc.Text` to a numeric value, before passing it to the `Format()` method.

You *could* do something like:

```
txtDisc.Text = Format(Val(txtDisc.Text), "0.00")
```

Or you could parse the value, and use the .Net methods (rather than the VB6 compatibility methods), so something like:

```
Dim disc As Double
If Double.TryParse(txtDisc.Text, disc) Then
    txtDisc.Text = string.Format("{0:N2}", disc)
End If
```

Comment: The second example is best IMHO.

Comment: oh yes, it worked too.. I swear I tried the first example before same as written but I am surprised it worked now.. I was getting 0.00 values everytime before but it is working fine now...
Still I switched to 2nd example... Thanx alot

Answer (score 4):

First, you must parse your text input to get a numeric value. Then you can format it as you wish.

```vb
   txtDisc.Text = Format(Val(txtDisc.Text), "0.00")
```

Note: `Val` function is old approach, recommended one is through `Double.Parse()`, but I think in this simple example, you don't care.

Comment: okie worked for me....I tried that before also but it worked now.... Thanx for the help...

Answer (score 2):

You have to cast the text value to a number (double perhaps?) to perform format against.

Check this example:

```
Sub Main()
        Dim s As String = "12"
        Dim d As Double = Double.Parse(s)

        Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("#,##0.00"))
        Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("C1"))
        Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("C3"))
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:C2}", d))
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:C5}", d))

        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
```

"C" is for currency

Comment: You did not explain the asker what he did wrong. This could be optimised :)

Comment: I seen that in msdn help.. there was F for fixed value to do it as I want but that even not worked...
The both answers given above worked so I am satisfied...Thanks anyways...