# (vb.net) rounding to 2 decimal places

Tags: vb.net, variables, decimal

I am creating a program for a project that will help me learn visual basic. But when I work out how much a certain material is worth with dimensions. It come out with more than two decimal places. I know how to use math.floor function but it doesn't round to 2 decimal places.

Does anyone know what function I should use to round to two decimal places?

Comment: `Math.Round(yourNumber, 2)`. Is it so hard to use the search function or ask google?

Comment: Loads of examples of this all over the Internet on how this can be done. Possible duplicate of [How to convert answer into two decimal point in vb.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16581901/how-to-convert-answer-into-two-decimal-point-in-vb-net)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because a simple google search will turn up the answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert answer into two decimal point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16581901/how-to-convert-answer-into-two-decimal-point)

Comment: The proposed duplicate does not show how to round **down** to 2 decimal places, which the OP seems to be asking for (based of the reference to Math.Floor).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Decimal.Round](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6be1edhb(v=vs.110).aspx) method will do the trick for you.
You can specify the number of decimal places.

Comment: Note that this doesn't round down as Math.Floor does.

Answer (score 8):

You can use;

```
Math.Round([DECIMAL], 2)
```

If you want to round up you can use;

```
MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero
```

As an additional parameter to make;

```
Math.Round([DECIMAL], 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: MidPointRounding only decides if the answer should be rounding up or down if the answer is **exactly** xx.5 while the OP seems to want to **always** round down (based on the reference to Math.Floor).